# RESTFUL to SOAP conversion giving "Can't find the request for {URL}'s observer

Tags: java, rest, soap, cxf

I have been tasked with converting some of my project's RESTFUL services into SOAP. After a great deal of copypasta of functionality, and using one of our existing SOAP services as a model,  I was finally ready to deploy only to be met with

```
"WARNING: Can't find the request for http://localhost:9090/{ServiceName}/requirements/'s Observer
```

This is not my service's endpoint, which, according to my Tomcat manager is

```
http://localhost:9090/{ServiceName}/{ServiceName}
```

I have no idea how the word "requirements" got mixed into this, and can only guess it has something to do with RESTFUL, as its endpoint used the @Path annotation "/requirements/" However,  I have purged every reference to this class and that path from both the client and server projects, even going so far as to let IntelliJ do a file path search for the word "requirements".

What I've figured out thus far:
-The client is accessing the correct port. I have traced execution to when my client calls my port, and it's there that it fails.
-The server is capable of responding. I can manually navigate my browser to the URL for my SOAP services and execute them. They fail, but since I'm not passing them any request objects this way that's to be expected.

Relevant documents. If there are any others that may help, please say so:

### From applicationContext.xml

```
<jaxws:endpoint id="AMP" implementor="#ampWebServiceImpl" address="/AMPWebService/>
```

### From WSDL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions name="MAPWebService" targetNamespace="{URL}/services/AMPWebService" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:tns="{URL}/services/AMPWebService" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata">
...
<wsdl:types>
<xs:schema targetNamespace="{URL}/services/AMPWebService" xmlns:tns="{URL}/services/AMPWebService" xmlns:xmime="http://www.w3.org/2005/05/xmlmime">
...
</xs:schema>
</wsdl:types>
...
<!--Messages-->
...
<wsdl:portType name="AMPWebService">
...
<!--Operations-->
</wsdl:portType>
...
<wsdl:binding name="AMPWebServiceBinding" type="tns:AMPWebService">
<soap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
...
<!--operations-->
...
</wsdl:binding>
...
<wsdl:service name="AMPWebService">
<wsdl:port name="AMPWebServicePort" binding="tns:AMPWebServiceBinding">
<soap:address location="http://localhost:8088/mockAMPWebServiceBinding"/>
</wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```